# Check if List with multiple Columns contains string

Tags: c#, list

How do i check if the first column of my list RequirementList contains a string / element

```
 public class RequirementList
  {
    public string? Name{ get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
  }
```

Check here:

```
var requirementList = new List<RequirementList>();
//requirementList is already filled

  if(requirementList.Name.Contains("Test"))
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: `requirementList.Any(x => x.Name.Contains("Test"))`?

Comment: By column, do you mean the first property in the RequirementList object?

Comment: Yes, the name prop.

Comment: Maybe a matter of personal taste, but in my opinion it seems counter-intuitive to name the class Requirement*List* when the usage is *list item*. The term List tells me you are referring to a collection of items.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that Name can be null here, you should do it like this:

```
if(requirementList.Any(x=>x.Name is not null && x.Name.Contains("Test"))
```

Note that `Contains` here will be case sensitive. You can check this answer to handle case insensitivity [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Answer (score 0):

to complete or give another flavor with a modern c# you can write this as

```
if(requirementList.Any(x=>x?.Name.Contains("Test") ?? false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some misconceptions around lists and properties, so I'll try to make it a little more clear. Some of this has been mentioned by others.

First, don't call something list, if it isn't a list. `RequirementList` should be called `RequirementItem` or just `Requirement`.

Now your definition looks like this:

```cs
var requirementList = new List<Requirement>();
```

See, it's already more logical.

Second, Name and Value are properties of a Requirement, they are not columns and you shouldn't think of them as such. Hence *first* doesn't apply, there is no first property

```cs
public class Requirement
{
    public string? Name{ get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}
```

is equivalent to

```cs
public class Requirement
{
    public string? Value { get; set; }
    public string? Name{ get; set; }
}
```

And finally it looks like you want do something special to requirements with test in the name, so you should select the requirements first:

```cs
var requirementList = new List<Requirement>();
...
var testRequirements = requirementList.Select(x=>x?.Name.Contains("Test"));
if (testRequirements.Any())
{
    foreach (var req in testRequirements)
    {
        // do something with req
    }
}
```

This saves you the trouble of doing `Any` first and then select the ones you need to work with.